# Can't patch Android Studio from 1.3.0 to 1.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

On my laptop, I had AS version 1.3.2. When 1.4.0 got released into the stable channel, I got the usual **Update and Restart** option.

On my desktop however, I have AS version 1.3.0. Now it refuses to give me the Update option here and instead I only get the option to download the Standalone version and basically do a new installation.

Is there any workaround for this? I want to update my current 1.3.0 installation to 1.4.0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if you download it manually and try to install, it asks whether you want to install over the top of the existing application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually downloaded the latest version (1.4.0) zip, extracted it and copy-pasted the folders (all but plugins) into my older installation, over-writing where needed.

It worked. Do remember that the plugins folder needs to be replaced, not copied over. So deleted your old plugins folder and replace it with the new one.